# Sharepoint list data migration to database

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint list named commentList that has a column 'body'.i want to move the data that is stored in the 'body' column to sql server database.
How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your data by using SharePoint object model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server Integration Services there is a CodePlex solution:

[SharePoint List Source and Destination](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652)

Not sure if it is overkill for what you are trying to do though.